Does Fermat's Last Theorem work with rational exponents greater than 2?
I'm studying the fascinating book "Squigonometry: The Study of Imperfect Circles" which investigates the unit $p$-circles, in other words the curves $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$ (the Euclidean circumference is clearly the particular case $p=2$).
Exercise $3.7$ claims that for $p>2$ such that $\color{red}{p \in \mathbb{Q}}$ the only rational points (points where both coordinates are rational numbers) of the $p$-circles lie on the axes; equivalently, if $p>2$, $\color{red}{p \in \mathbb{Q}}$ and $(x, y)$ lies on the $p$-circle, then $x, y$ are both rational if and only if one of them is 0.
As the book suggests, there are rational points galore on the Euclidean circle, for instance $\left(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5} \right)$ or $\left(\frac{5}{13}, \frac{12}{13} \right)$, which are derivable from well-known Pythagorean triples. In fact, dividing both sides of $3^2+4^2=5^2$ by $5^2$ we get $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2 =1$.
Therefore, my idea to prove this statement is to follow the inverse path and apply Fermat's Last Theorem. Suppose $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{m}{n}$ with $a, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b, n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$. I want to prove that either $x=0$ or $y=0$.
We have $|\frac{a}{b}|^p+|\frac{m}{n}|^p=1$. Multiplying both sides by $|bn|^p$ we get $|an|^p+|bm|^p=|bn|^p$. Now, if $\color{blue}{p \in \mathbb{N}}$, this equation has solutions for $p>2$ if and only if either $|an|^p=0$ or $|bm|^p=0$, which in turn holds if and only if either $a=0$ or $m=0$, if and only if either $x=0$ or $y=0$.
However, I don't know how to proceed if $p$ is not a natural number. Does Fermat's Last Theorem hold for rational exponents too? Or should I consider it a typo by the authors?
P. S. I would appreciate suggestions for the tags to use.
EDIT: The (now deleted) answer provided by Hunter is a nice trick to prove that Fermat's Last Theorem does not hold in general for $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ as it suffices to take any equality $a+b=c$ and write it as $(a^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} +(b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (c^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\frac{1} {n} \in \mathbb{Q}$. However, $\frac{1} {n} < 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, I would like to know if this argument might be extended in some way to make it work for exponents greater than 2, to see if there is a mistake in the book.

On this paper from $2004$ by Curtis D. Bennett, A. M. W. Glass, and Gaibor J. Sz6kely, the question you pose is adressed, with the main result, stated as "Theorem 1" showing that:
1. If $m$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers with $n \gt 2$, then solutions to
$\large a^\frac{n}{m} + b^\frac{n}{m} = c^\frac{n}{m}$ in positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ occur only if $a = b = c,$ $m$ is
divisible by $6$, and three different complex $6th$ roots are used.
They go about proving it using Fermat's Last Theorem, as well as a result from Galois Theory and basic trigonometry.

I don't understand what "and three different complex 6th roots are used" means. Also, could you please explain further how this theorem solves my doubt?

Proposition 7 (or the entire section 2) of the linked paper might be more fitting here. There they show that no non-trivial solutions to $x^{n/m}+y^{n/m}=1$ with $n>2$ exist in the real case.
